# Java - Unknown attribute MS-CHAP-Challenge

Tags: java, exception, attributes, radius

I am following [this](http://www.coova.org/node/3333/8057#comment-8057) little example in java, to test JRadius client. 
But I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jradius.exception.UnknownAttributeException: Unknown attribute MS-CHAP-Challenge
at net.sf.jradius.packet.attribute.AttributeFactory.newAttribute(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jradius.client.auth.MSCHAPv2Authenticator.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jradius.client.RadiusClient.authenticate(Unknown Source)
at lu.restena.zimbra.RestenaAuthenticator.main(RestenaAuthenticator.java:94)
```

I have added all jars already and imports too.

My code:

> ```
>         InetAddress remoteInetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(RADIUSname);
>         RadiusClient radiusClient;
>         radiusClient = new RadiusClient(
>                 remoteInetAddress,   // InetAddress - Address of remote RADIUS Server
>                 sharedSecret); // String - Shared Secret for remote RADIUS Server
>         AttributeList attributeList;
>         attributeList = new AttributeList();
>         attributeList.add(new Attr_UserName(username));
>         RadiusAuthenticator auth = RadiusClient.getAuthProtocol("mschapv2");
>         RadiusPacket request;
>         request = new AccessRequest(radiusClient, attributeList);
>         request.addAttribute(new Attr_UserPassword(password));
>         RadiusPacket reply = radiusClient.authenticate((AccessRequest) request, auth, 5);
> ```

The error is on:

```
RadiusPacket reply = radiusClient.authenticate((AccessRequest) request, auth, 5);
```

Anyone has any idea why? (I am a newbie in JRadius) ([MSCHAPv2Authenticator.java](http://cadbis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CADBiS_jradius/src/net/jradius/client/auth/MSCHAPv2Authenticator.java))

Answer (score 1):

Before using the JRadius library, a JRadius dictionary should be loaded as below.

```
AttributeFactory.loadAttributeDictionary("net.jradius.dictionary.AttributeDictionaryImpl");
```

Also, ensure you have added JRadius Dictionary (jradius-dictionary-.jar) to you class path.